# searchbar/did select-deselect ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have seen some git hub project and SO question ,that some used search bar programatically for their project.I too followed this project [project](https://github.com/ihomam/CollectionViewWithSearchBar).In that they created the search bar object and placed it.But at last they added one method "observer".Really i can't understand that menthod.If i run my app without that method .Not able to see my search bar

Actually there is any method called "observer".i am new to ios so only having this doubt.

Another question:

To delect and de-select the collection view cell. i did with below code.But when i select one cell it background color is changed but when i select the same cell again it not showing to my default didde-select method.If i select other cell only my first selected cell are change to white color as per the did-de select method

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];

}

//did-deselect
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}
```

This is way the collection view cell select/did de select will work.Thanks!

Edited:

I use some login logout for my projets which have some collection view.I used search bar like added in that above git hub project i gave.When i press logout button my app crash.

this is my logout code:

```
- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



}
```

when i remove `addobserber` method from my project its working well.But i need that to display my search bar.if i use my app crash when i press logout

But i did't use this code:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    // remove Our KVO observer
    [self removeObservers];
}
```

Does it needed to insert my code to work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For your 1st question:**

In the project you are adding observer to the `collection view`

```
- (void)addObservers{
    [self.collectionView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}
```

So that if there are any changes regarding the `collectionView` `contentOffset`, it will call the following method and changes the search bar frame:

```
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(UICollectionView *)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"] && object == self.collectionView ) {
    self.searchBar.frame = //.....
   }
}
```

In your project, this method deals with the search bar frame. So, don't remove the method unless you really dont find any use of it. If you dont find your search bar, you are missing it. In that case, you need to set the search bar frame somewhere in your code.

**For your 2nd question:**

*"To delect and de-select the collection view cell. i did with below code.But when i select one cell it background color is changed but when i select the same cell again it not showing to my default didde-select method."*

It doesnt work like that. When you select the cell again, the method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` will get called and you dont see the white color for it.

The cell only gets deSelected, if you select another cell. If you want to deSelect the cells manually, you need to call `deselectItemAtIndexPath`. Again, if you do this on `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` , you dont find much difference as it gets deselected immediatley right after you select the cell!!!!

Comment: i use `addObservers`  with login logot.But when i press logout button my app getting crash

Comment: `- (IBAction)logOut:(id)sender {
    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: this above code i am using for log out.If i remove observers its work fine.But i need this method. Now how to do that..

Comment: pls update your question with the the code and with as much as info as u can which will help us to understand ur question better

Comment: by adding dealloc method its working fine....Actually  what is observer? .as you said in your answer i am adding observer to collection view??. And why we use dealloc method here?? in comment line they said remove kvo obsorver??? really don't know about this.please help me and explain

Comment: We use dealloc to remove  objects from the memory. All other elements are deallocated by ARC. As you added observer, you need to remove it whenever you move away from the screen. Hence you remove it in dealloc